# Examine multiple locations in a line for data using awk

Tags: parsing, awk, dynamic

I am trying to extract some information that was originally sourced from a mainframe. The rows are all just ASCII character data, but each row is considered multi-segment, so has differing line lengths. Fields are length delimited. There is a field in the row that dictates how many segments of the row to expect for the variable portion. What I want to do is look for the presence of an indicator in those variable segments, and extract some data from it.

A simplified example is shown below;

```
UUID12345 1   ABC 1 345  
UUID23456 2   XYZ 4 763 ABC 4 678  
UUID34567 3   XYZ 4 763 ABC 2 456 QRS 2 456  
UUID45678 2   DEF 1 345 TUV 8 111 
UUID56789 0
```

The second column dictates how many segments to expect. There *can be* up to 99 segments, but in reality, there are less than 10. In the example above, each segment would contain 10 bytes starting at the position of ABC on the first line for example. What I want to extract is the first column of each line and the value that is the last 3 characters of any segment containing ABC.

So an example output could for the above row would be;

```
UUID12345 345  
UUID23456 678  
UUID34567 456
UUID45678 
UUID56789
```

I know some very basic awk, and can look for specific sections of a line, but don't know how to achieve what I need to for this. For example, the following provides me the ability to extract the first line, but only by looking at specific locations, and doesn't take into account the 2nd column indicating the variable number of segments.

```
awk '{ if (substr($0, 0, 4)=="UUID" && substr($0, 15, 3)=="ABC") {print substr($0, 0, 9) " " substr ($0, 21,3)}}' <<< "UUID12345 1   ABC 1 345"
```

**Edit**

As per my comment to Ed Morton below, this is what I ended up with that works for me (where test.txt is the example shown above);

```
awk '{segs=substr($0, 11, 1); acc=substr($0, 1, 10); startCol=15; val=""; for(i=startCol; i<startCol+(10 * segs); i+= 10) if (substr($0, i, 3)=="ABC") val=substr($0, i + 6, 3); print acc " " segs " " val}' test.txt
```

Comment: According to your description, the line starting UUID45678 should have 2 segments but it only contains 1.

Comment: Good pickup. I've edited the example.

Comment: Some more clarifications, can a line contain multiple ABC segments? Is format always 3x letter, space, 1x digit, space, 3x digit? You say final 3 chars, but you actual took 7,8,9 not 8,9,10. Some of your example data lines end with two spaces, some with one and the last one has none. Is this true of the actual data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{val=""; for (i=3; i<NF; i+=3) if ($i=="ABC") val=$(i+2); print $1, val}' file
UUID12345 345
UUID23456 678
UUID34567 456
UUID45678
UUID56789
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output that better captures all your requirements.

Comment: this isn't quite right for me as my file has fixed field lengths, but some fields are optional. Therefore the number of fields per line varies between 61 and 95. However, the area where my multisegment data starts is in a fixed position, so I just took your example and modified it and it worked! I updated my question with the fix that addressed the issue for me. Let me know if there are any issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way with awk :

```
awk -F'ABC' '{split($1,a," |\t");split($2,b," |\t");print a[1],b[3]}' infile
```

Comment: Nice. While this also works for my contrived example above, my real files have lines that are ~1000 characters long, and each field in the file is a fixed length, with some fields optional. Therefore, this wouldn't work on my real file, but it certainly is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl

```
$ perl -lane ' ($x)=$_=~/\bABC\s+\S+\s+(\S+)/; print $F[0], " ", $x ' moose.txt
UUID12345 345
UUID23456 678
UUID34567 456
UUID45678
UUID56789

$ cat moose.txt
UUID12345 1   ABC 1 345
UUID23456 2   XYZ 4 763 ABC 4 678
UUID34567 3   XYZ 4 763 ABC 2 456 QRS 2 456
UUID45678 2   DEF 1 345 TUV 8 111
UUID56789 0

$
```